# Prove $\mid\mathbb{N}\mid \leq \, \mid \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to prove that $$\mid\mathbb{N}\mid \leq \, \mid \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid$$

I assume that I need to show that there is function $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is one-to-one , But I couln't find one.. :\

Can you find such function ? or maybe a different way to prove this ?                    Thanks.

Comment: Notice that for this inequality you need to find a function which is merely injective, not necessarily onto. This should be quite easy.

Comment: if you know what  $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$   is, you should be able to construct at least one such function trivially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many choices, but one simple one is:
$$ f(n)=(n,n,n,\dots)$$
That is, map each natural number $n$ to the sequence in which every term is $n$.

Comment: Odds are good the reason the OP had the problem with this is not that he can't come up with a suitable example, but rather that he doesn't really understand what is he supposed to do (otherwise the problem is trivial). I think in this situation it is preferred not to reveal the final answer immediately.

Comment: @Blazej: I could be wrong, but it certainly seems to me that the OP knew he was looking for an example of an injective function, and just couldn't find one.